# Sending SMS Text Messages to Another Person's Android Cellphone From My Laptop

Tags: android, email

Here's the Problem:  My grandson has a Android cellphone that can do SMS.
He wants me to contact him from my laptop with text messages.  He can email me from his cellphone, so why can't I email him?

I'm looking at all these postings, and it mostly about using a laptop or desktop in conjunction with the user's cellphone.  That's not what I am going for.  I don't have a cellphone and don't want one.  I have Ubuntu 14.04 if that is important.

Answer (score 1):

In your email client, you should be able to write an email and have it sent to his cell phone.  Check what carrier his cell phone is with, then you can check this list [here](http://www.emailtextmessages.com/) and see what the address is that you send the message to.

Example, if he was with Sprint, you would email your message to

```
phonenumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com
```

replacing `phonenumber` with his cell number.

Hope this helps!